# Sudoku Project crashes on runtime

Tags: debugging, crash, sudoku

I'm trying to prepare a Sudoku project. I have row and column controls for now. 
If I create an array 9*9 program crashes on runtime and the form window freezes. I stop it by clicking "Stop Debugging" button. But it works perfect with a small array. For example 3*3. If I create 6*6 and more sometimes works, sometimes doesn't work. But 9*9 I couldn't get success so far.

What is the problem, do you have any idea about this problem?..
I'm new on programming. I'll be glad if you write the answers with some examples.

Thanks in advance..

Just a part from codes. I changed variables in English..

```
    public bool rowControl(int[,] sudoku, int row, int value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (sudoku[row, i] == value)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool columnControl(int[,] sudoku, int column, int value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (sudoku[i, column == value)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int f = 0; f < 9; f++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                while (rowControl(sudokuArr, f, random) == false || columnControl(sudokuArr, i, random) == false)
                {
                    random= r.Next(1, 10);
                }
                sudokuArr[f, i] = random;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Beyond one bug (presumably a typo) and a couple places that could be written better, but are fine as is, it appears your code is correct.  Are you sure the program crashes here?  Your bug is in `columnControl`, you have this erroneous code: `if (sudoku[i, column == value)` - no ending brace `]`.

Comment: If my array is 9*9 program doesn't answer. I stop it from Stop button on VS. But if I create 3*3 array, it works without any problems.

Comment: You stated that in the question.  VS should tell you which line your code crashes at.  If you want, you can post your entire project somewhere, and I will load it into my computer and test it.

Comment: http://dosya.co/9s0cz6ugqzuy/Sudoku2.rar.html

Comment: Sory but I couldn't write in other comment :) I have loded it.. I'm new on programming. I'm just trying something and I know that it can be done in different ways. But I don't know them. :)

Comment: You can try it 4-5 times. It won't work. But sometimes works..

Comment: I am not sure what is going on here.  I am sorry to say it, but this code looks like a complete mess, and it would probably be quicker for me to write a sudoku solver and give it to you than debug this.  One tip, why are you iterating over values based on randomly chosen numbers with a `while` loop?  Do you realize that any given number could never come up?  You should iterate over the 9 possible values with a `for` loop instead.

Comment: I used random number because computer will fill blank cells. Do you think that because of theese random numbers?

Comment: I am not sure.  I couldn't even fix the number of cells you had to 9x9.  Your program was filling an 8x8 area, you have a 9x10 grid.  I messed around with a lot of things, but I couldn't get even this to work.  I am not sure at all why it does it, but I would guess that it at least partially involves the random numbers because it is sporadic and not consistent.

Comment: Yes. It's 9*10 but it's my fault. I must to delete them. I just set 8*8 array to try. Anyway. Could you please give me an idea to do Sudoku. I mean what kind of algorithm I must use. This is my first project(homework) with c#.

Comment: Try one of these, especially read the Wiki article to get the general idea: http://www.bing.com/search?q=sudoku+solver+algorithm&qs=AS&pq=sudoku+solver+algo&sc=1-18&sp=1&cvid=d44d3442cabc40c881f0208cf556df82&FORM=QBRE&ghc=1

Comment: I think that will be useful. I'll try this. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hello again. I'm sorry if I disturb you but I prepared a new project. I think this is better. I get same problem. I guess the problem is looping. Code creates numbers, doesn't stop and repeats creating. In the codes you can see a line for a MessageBox. It stops the proekt and it works.. Could you please check it now? How can I stop the loop?http://dosya.co/ypx98nduqltr/SudokuENG.rar.html

Comment: No problem.  In `BSudoku()`, you have a StackOverflow.  Working on re-writing it now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know what your original problem was, but your problem after the revision was recursively calling `BSudoku` until you had a StackOverflow error.  This code wort of works:

```
namespace Sudoku
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        static TextBox[,] graphicSudokuBoard;

        int[,] field = new int[9, 9];

        public void CreateSudokuBoard()
        {
            int x = 10, y = 10;
            int tabIndex = 0, textBoxHeight = 0;

            graphicSudokuBoard = new TextBox[9, 9];

            for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
            {
                x = 10;

                for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
                {
                    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                    textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                    textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font.FontFamily, 24F, FontStyle.Bold);
                    textBox.MaxLength = 1;
                    textBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    textBox.Width = textBox.Height;
                    textBox.TabIndex = tabIndex++;

                    textBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
                    this.Controls.Add(textBox);

                    graphicSudokuBoard[row, col] = textBox;
                    textBoxHeight = textBox.Height;

                    x += textBox.Width - 1;
                    if (col % 3 == 2)
                        x++;
                }

                y += textBoxHeight - 1;
                if (row % 3 == 2)
                    y++;
            }
        }

        bool chkRow(int row, int value, int[,] arr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (arr[row, i] == value)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        bool chkColumn(int column, int value, int[,] arr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i, column] == value)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        bool chkSquare(int row, int column, int value, int[,] arr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[row - (row % 3) + i, column - (column % 3) + j] == value)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        bool chkAll(int row, int column, int value, ref int[,] arr)
        {
            if (!chkRow(row, value, arr))
                return false;
            if (!chkColumn(column, value, arr))
                return false;
            if (!chkSquare(row, column, value, arr))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        int[,] BSudoku(int value, int px, int py, int[,] field)
        {
            int[,] sudokuCells = new int[9, 9];

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    sudokuCells[j, i] = field[j, i];
                }
            }

            for (int x = px; x < 9; x++)
            {
                for (int y = py; y < 9; y++)
                {
                    if (sudokuCells[x, y] == 0)
                    {
                        for (int val = 1; val <= 9; val++)
                        {
                            if (val == 9 && !chkAll(x, y, val, ref sudokuCells))
                            {
                                sudokuCells[x, y] = 0;
                                if (x > 0 || y > 0)
                                {
                                    if (x > 0 && y == 0)
                                    {
                                        x--;
                                        y = 8;
                                    }
                                    else y--;
                                }
                                while(sudokuCells[x,y] == 9)
                                {
                                    sudokuCells[x, y] = 0;
                                    if (x > 0 || y > 0)
                                    {
                                        if (x > 0 && y == 0)
                                        {
                                            x--;
                                            y = 8;
                                        }
                                        else y--;
                                    }
                                }
                                sudokuCells[x, y]++;
                            }
                            if (chkAll(x, y, val, ref sudokuCells))
                            {
                                sudokuCells[x, y] = val;
                                graphicSudokuBoard[x, y].Text = sudokuCells[x, y].ToString();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    graphicSudokuBoard[j, i].Text = sudokuCells[j, i].ToString();
                }
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("Done!");
            return sudokuCells;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    string s = graphicSudokuBoard[i, j].Text;
                    if (s == "") s = "0";
                    field[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(s);
                }
            }

            BSudoku(0, 0, 0, field);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateSudokuBoard();
        }
    }
}
```

I had to correct MANY problems.  One, you cannot have your `chk___` functions be static.  This will never let your loop variables start back at 0 once they return.  I don't remember everything I fixed, but as a warning, most SO people will not take this time to go over your code.  The above code solves the StackOverflow problem, and many other problems.  If you seed it with enough values, it will return the correct function, but there are a few problems left where it allows multiple values to be in a row, column, and square.  One other thing, you may want to pass your arrays as a reference using the `ref` keyword; this will speed your code by a good deal.  As a last warning, because this is a brute-force solver, you need to seed it with several values for it to run reasonably fast.  It goes fast when three rows are filled for me, but produces an incorrect result.  You should be able to work that problem out, and I don't have the time to figure out what is happening right now.

Comment: Oh no.. I knew that this is backtracking algorithm. Do You mean I have to start from the begining? :( I have to do it with bt algorithm and I have to find a correct example. This was an example for backtracking on internet.

Comment: @DegetThe Well, your backtracking algo was the problem - you called it recursively, and you didn't need to - just backtrack.  I changed it so it doesn't call recursively, I fixed major bugs in your `chk___` functions, and I set the field to be the current state of the board instead of all 0's.  There are still bugs in the backtracking algo, but you should be able to solve it yourself now.  I am sorry, but I cannot work on the code side of this anymore because I just got a LOT of school work to do.  Good luck!